# C# SendInput user32.ddl. Al pulsar una tecla simular que se presionan otras

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que al pulsar una tecla se simule que se presione una tecla. Por ejemplo al pulsar la v que se simule que se presiona x tecla.

Actualmente he conseguido que al pulsar una tecla se mande la letra q pero no simula que presiona la letra q, solo manda el texto y lo que yo quiero es que simule que la presiona. Como en el autohotkey el famoso SendInput.

Basicamente quiero programar este codigo que funciona en ahk pero en c#:

$capslock::
sendinput q
return

Y esto es lo que tengo por ahora:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.CapsLock) < 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                       
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{q}");
                        Thread.Sleep(250);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], lenguaje C o C#?

Comment: Muéstranos lo que has intentado

Comment: Gracias por responder!